# REGEX : Match after A to the last B but only before C

Tags: regex

I would like to match everything after `\t(\fn` but *only* before `\`*and* excluding the last bracket that belongs to the `\(t` (as you can see on the attached picture)

For this :

```
\t(\fnJester (BIG))
\t(\fnJester (BIG))\i1
\t(\fnJester (BIG)
\t(\fnJester))))\fnArial (BOLD)\
```

I want to match :

```
Jester (BIG)
Jester (BIG)
Jester (BIG
Jester)))) and Arial (BOLD
```

I'm almost there with this pattern :

```
(?<=\\t\(.*?\\fn).*(?=\)|\\)
```

But since it's greedy, it matches everything even after `\`

https://regex101.com/r/YzY2KN/3

[image: brackets to ignore]

Comment: Literally all the blue characters on the picture. In other words everything after \fn and before the closest \, excluding the last bracket of the line.

Comment: Right, it's like on the 3rd line, in this case, everything before the last bracket, so \t(\fnJester (BIG))) would match Jester (BIG))

Comment: But it's the exact same pattern that I used in regex101. Unfortunately it's greedy so it matches after \ like in the four line of my examples.

Comment: No the last line of my example is \t(\fnJester))))\fnArial (BOLD)\ and it should match Jester)))) and Arial (BOLD
Ignore the fact that it doesn't make sense in terms of font name of course.
Such a pattern will match everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match the regular expression

```
(?<=fn)[^\\]*(?=\)|\\fn)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CGSxbe/1)

The expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?<=     # begin a positive lookbehind
  fn     # match 'fn'
)        # end positive lookbehind
[^\\]*   # match zero or more chars other than '\'
(?=      # begin a positive lookahead
  \)     # match ')'
  |      # or
  \\fn   # match '\fn\
)        # end positive lookahead
```

Comment: Thank you. Same question as above : Is it possible that the pattern doesn't rely on an \fn being after a bracket ? Because in ass subtiles you can have any tag like \b1 or \blur, which would make the pattern avoid a bracket because it doesn't find \fn regex101.com/r/zx1GAi/1

Comment: As I understand, in `\t(\xxJester (BIG))` `xx` can be `fn`, `b1`, `blur` or something else. Is `xx` always a string of lowercase letters and does the word that follows (`Jester` in the example) always begin with a capital letter?

Comment: No, it's always \fnJester (BIG) but it's not always \fnJester (BIG)\fnArial. It can be \fnJester (BIG)\b1\blur5 for instance. And tags always in lowercase btw.

Comment: The example `'\fnJester (BIG)\b1\blur5'` complicates the problem considerably. I suggest you ask a separate question.

Comment: I also think that's better. This question is answered by both of you. Thanks again for helping.

Comment: @andiandi: Both solutions work for given samples but just understand small difference. This regex will not work if \ is found anywhere in the middle of the text like `\t(\fnJeste\r (BIG))\i1`

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for the precision. I'm coupling this regex with another regex to match the others simple \fn tags so it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex:

```sh
(?<=\\fn).*?(?=\\fn|\)(?:\\(?!fn)|$))
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YzY2KN/7)

`(?=\\fn|\)(?:\\(?!fn)|$))` is the lookahead condition that is making sure that our match is ending with `\fn` or `)` followed by optional `\`.

Comment: It's almost perfect. The issue is that in multiple \fn tags occurences, it doesn't match all brackets except the last one. So for instance in : \t(\fnJester))))\fnArial (BOLD)\ I want to match  Jester)))) (all brackets) and Arial (BOLD. Also, for : \t(\fnJester))))\fnArial (BOLD)\fnArial (BOLD)\ I want to match Jester)))) (all brackets) Arial (BOLD) and Arial (BOLD    (no bracket for this last)

Comment: You are contradicting your comment of `Yes, that's right !`. Try and understand that first

Comment: That's my bad, I thought you were talking about isolated Jester)))). I deleted the comment.
So to be clear this time it should match Jester)))) and Arial(BOLD in "\fnJester))))\fnArial (Bold)"

Comment: ok check my updated answer

Comment: Your demo doesn't match the blue selected characters in OP's test case

Comment: @anubhava Just checked again and it does work actually. The UI on that website is weird and makes it look like an incorrect match

Comment: Is it possible that the pattern doesn't rely on an \fn being after a bracket ? Because in ass subtiles you can have any tag like \b1 or \blur, which would make the pattern avoid a bracket because it doesn't find \fn https://regex101.com/r/zx1GAi/1

Comment: Maybe this ?
(?<=\\fn).*?(?=\\.*\\|\)(?:\\(?!\\.*\\)|$))

Comment: `Is it possible that the pattern doesn't rely on an \fn being after a bracket`. It will be possible if you state all your requirements **clearly** in question upfront. It is not a good practice to keep changing requirements like this. My solution fully meets your original requirements already.

Comment: Fair enough, you did answer my original requirements thanks.